# Which will be better declaration go to with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is a simple question, but during my migration to TypeScript, I'm seeing that in many cases my code could take these two directions... which one could be a better direction to go with: `class.ts` or `interface.ts`?

**class.ts**

```
export class ActionSet {   
  constructor(private name: string) {}

  get ACTION(): string {
    return this.name;   
  }

  get PENDING(): string {
    return `${this.name}_PENDING`;   
  }

  get FULFILLED(): string {
    return `${this.name}_FULFILLED`;   
  }

  get REJECTED(): string {
    return `${this.name}_REJECTED`;   
  }
}

export function createActionSet(name: string): ActionSet {   
  return new ActionSet(name); 
}
```

**interface.ts**

```
export interface IActionSet {
  ACTION: string;
  PENDING: string;
  FULFILLED: string;
  REJECTED: string;
}

export function createActionSet(name: string): IActionSet {
  return {
    ACTION: name,
    PENDING: `${name}_PENDING`,
    FULFILLED: `${name}_FULFILLED`,
    REJECTED: `${name}_REJECTED`
  };
}
```

*A more visual way:*

[image]

Due to `ActionSet` is not being used in many places, will it be worth to create a class for it? or is this implementation an overkill?

Comment: looks like question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: @MozgovoyArtem thanks, create https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194091/which-will-be-better-declaration-go-to-with-typescript

Comment: The two solutions are fine. There is no bad choice here. You could use `Object.freeze` on the object created in `interfaces.ts`, and mark the properties as `readonly` in the interface.

Comment: I found both solutions are fine. But using interface would be much cleaner choice to make, as this would be useful for mapping data into expected modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two solutions are fine. There is no bad choice here. So, it is not a real answer but a comment, here.

## Why to prefer a `class`

1. At runtime, you can use `instanceof`;
2. It is DRY. You don't have to write separately the contract (the `interface`) and the implementation (the factory);
3. It is more OOP;
4. The memory footprint is smaller.

## Why to prefer an `interface`

1. At compile time, you can use intersections, unions, [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick) etc., on interfaces;
2. At runtime, you can use `Object.keys`, `Object.assign` etc., on the objects;
3. The performance: because in the class version, a getter and a string concatenation is less performant than just read a property;
4. The bundled size.

A small tip: do not use a prefix `I` for interfaces. Otherwise, which prefix will you use for a type like:

```
type WhichPrefixForThatType = MyInterface | boolean;
```

## A last consideration: think JavaScript

TypeScript is JavaScript with types. It is not an independent language. So, to evaluate what are good practices in TypeScript, remember to look at the equivalent JavaScript code.

You can compare the version with a class:

```
export class ActionSet {   
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  get ACTION() {
    return this.name;   
  }

  get PENDING() {
    return `${this.name}_PENDING`;   
  }

  get FULFILLED() {
    return `${this.name}_FULFILLED`;   
  }

  get REJECTED() {
    return `${this.name}_REJECTED`;   
  }
}

export function createActionSet(name) {   
  return new ActionSet(name); 
}
```

The version with an interface:

```
export function createActionSet(name) {
  return Object.freeze({
    ACTION: name,
    PENDING: `${name}_PENDING`,
    FULFILLED: `${name}_FULFILLED`,
    REJECTED: `${name}_REJECTED`
  });
}
```

In your example, the second one seems to be simpler to write and to read.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Paleo, it is very useful and in this case and due to the kind of problem I have to resolve, I'll go for the `interface` implementation. 

About the `I` meanwhile I was uploading this code I was disabling it on my tslint config :) ... after being used I realise it is a very bad choice.